# Exclude worst value from weighted arithmetic mean

Tags: statistics, average, means

I'm working on a tournament rating, that is calculated as a weighted arithmetic mean, i.e. the formula is:
$$
R = \frac{a_1 x_1+a_2 x_2+\cdots+a_n x_n}{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n}
$$
$a_i$ is a positive tournament weight.
$x_i$ is a non-negative tournament score.

The formula has one particularity, though: one or a few *worst* results  (let's say 10% of them) are excluded from it. In other words, I need to find which values to exclude (i.e. set $a_i=0$) to maximize the $R$ value.

How can I find which values to exclude without brute-force search?

Comment: Unless $n$ is very large it can't to be too 'brutal' a search to find the scores in the lowest 10% and exclude them.  Some scoring methods (e.g., Olympic) just eliminate the highest and lowest (without weights). Unweighted averages that disregard the lowest and highest 5% of the data are called 5% trimmed means. Here are 20 observations, sorted in order: `20 20 22 23 25 25 27 28 28 28 29 29 31 32 32 33 34 38 38 46` From R statistical software, the mean, 5% trimmed mean, and median are 29.4, 29.0, 28.5, respectively.